# How to get some values from json saved in nsstring?

Tags: iphone, json, nsurlconnection, nsdata

My WS returns simple json like this:

```
{
  "thumbnail_url": "http://something.com/photos/003/582/test-tiny.jpg?1321956139",
  "success": true,
  "photo_url": "http://something.com/photos/003/582/test-medium.jpg?1321956139",
  "big_photo_url": "http://something.com/photos/003/582/test-big.jpg?1321956139"
}
```

I get this in NSData from NSURLConnection. I know how to make NSString from NSData. I would like to get value for "photo_url" key.

How can it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use SBJSON framework to get value of photo_url.

in SBJSON framework have one method that return NSMutableDictionary For String.

You can use like this  `[string JSONValue]`  that will return NSMutableDictionary.

After that use will be get value from this code  `[dict valueForKey:@"photo_url"]`

Thanks,

MinuMaster

Answer (score 0):

Use [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON) or [SBJson](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/) parser to parse this.

Comment: I would sugest [JSONkit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit), because it the fasting thing out there. Here is some nice info on parsing JSON: http://triplesoftware.nl/2011/08/json-parsing/

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 5 only you can use the built in [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

If you need to support iOS4 then [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) is a good solution.

You can then query your results like a normal dictionary.